# Eager loading with dynamic condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have 4 models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

I need to fetch all the categories that have posts with comments made by a certain user.
I'm generating a json that has all the categories and the posts, but not the comments.

The query I'm using:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts => :comments).where(:comments => { :user_id => params[:user_id] } )
```

I'm using rabl:

```
collection @categories
attributes ...
child :posts do
  attributes ...
end
```

But this is getting all the comments.
If I use joins instead of includes I will have the n+1 problem.

How should I make the query?

Answer (score 1):

The `includes` method only helps with eager loading, it will not help you fetch the propper records.

What you need is probably something like this:

```
# get all posts with comments made by the user
posts = Post.where(:comments => { :user_id => params[:user_id] })
# fetch the categories for those posts
@categories = Category.find(posts.map(&:category_id).uniq)
```